# Regex for getting all words and punctuations from a string with html

Tags: regex, posix

I'm having trouble coming up with a regex statement that grabs all words and punctuation from a string that looks like

```
<p>hello my name is foo.</p><p>I like to go to the bar.</p>
```

My desired result is...

'hello' 'my' 'name' 'is' 'foo.' ..etc

The paragraph tag and white space need to be excluded. The regex will go into the  git diff --word-diff-regex='insert regex here' which uses bash

Thanks

EDIT

git uses POSIX for it's regex. Look arounds aren't supported

Comment: Try `<[^>]+>(*SKIP)(*F)|\S+` (if PCRE is available).

Comment: That worked only when I added spaces before the </p> tag

Comment: So, it seems PCRE is installed. Try `<[^>]+>(*SKIP)(*F)|[^\s<]+`

Comment: Opps sorry that worked in regex101.com but when I ran it with git it said Invalid regular expression

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using it with git-diff and since git is mostly in C it'd be what ever comes with that

Comment: git uses POSIX 1003.2 for it's regex

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this:

```
<.*?>|([\w.]+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/TzFmOD/1)**